# Incrementing a string by one in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to find a way to increment a specific pattern required. For each new member, they are given a unique ID such as **ABC000001**. Each new members ID should increment by one. So the second member's ID would be **ABC000002**. I am using PHP and MySQL to keep track of each member but I have not been able to come up with a way to properly increment using the string format above.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Don't increment the string. Increment the integer and then prefix the string.

Comment: PHP is able to increment your string: https://3v4l.org/l3OGS You'll probably regret later, when you'll get multiple entries in the database having the same ID :D

Comment: define an autoincrement column and prefixID then concat them

Comment: @AlexHowansky Okay, I understand that. But how do I keep the correct number of zeros prefixed once the number gets higher? For example, ABC002345?

Comment: str_pad can fill in zeros. Is there any reason you have to make it look like this? If you are trying to make a unique non-int-like string for each member, you could do it differently with a guid system.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes, we have a new partnership that is requiring this specific format.

Comment: Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

Comment: @three3 ... oh, perfectly understandable there... I hate dealing with 3rd parties for this very reason ;)

Comment: `$id = sprintf('%s%06d', $prefix, $num);`

Comment: @IncredibleHat same here, I do not know who comes up with this stuff lol. Not sure why they cannot stick with normal conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @axiac mentions this is probably not a good idea but it's pretty easy to manage.

```
$memberid = 'ABC000001';
list($mem_prefix,$mem_num) = sscanf($memberid,"%[A-Za-z]%[0-9]");
echo $mem_prefix . str_pad($mem_num + 1,6,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Split your current member number into the alpha and numeric parts then put them back together bumping the number when you do it. I use this as a function and pass the previous ID and what I get back is the next ID in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract only digits using regex to increment and using str_pad for create a prefix :

```
$memberid = 'ABC000001';
$num = preg_replace('/\D/', '',$memberid);
echo sprintf('ABC%s', str_pad($num + 1, "6", "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer without regex.
Runs through each character and checks if it is a number or not.
Then uses sprintf() to make sure leading 0s are still there.

```
$str = "ABC000001";
$number = "";
$prefix = "";
$strArray = str_split($str);
foreach ($strArray as $char) {  
    if (is_numeric($char))  {
        $number .= $char;   
    } else {
        $prefix .= $char;   
    }
}
$length = strlen($number);

$number = sprintf('%0' . $length . 'd', $number + 1);
echo $prefix . $number;
```

This works for this instance but would not work if the prefix had numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

just use the PHP increment operator ++

as long as you've sufficient leading zeros in the pattern, then PHP will correctly increment the numeric component

This code:

```
<?php
$name = 'ABC0000098';
print ++$name . PHP_EOL;
print ++$name . PHP_EOL;
print ++$name . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

```
ABC0000099
ABC0000100
ABC0000101
```

Read more in the PHP docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

- aha - just saw there is already a link to a similar example in the comment posted by "axiac" above