# How I can create alphanumeric autoincrement sequence in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to generate alphanumeric sequence value in mysql as following...

```
A0001
A0002
A0003
.
.
A9999
B0001
B0002
B0003
.
.
B9999
```

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757703/incrementing-a-string-by-one-in-php/49757917#49757917) might be helpful.